# How to generalize combinations

Tags: algorithm, math, linear-algebra

Working on auto generate configuration files.
I have a combinations with 3 factors:

```
{a1,m1,c1}
{a1,m1,c2}
{a1,m2,c1}
{a2,m1,c1}
{a2,m1,c2}
```

Now I want to "compress" these 5 expressions into as few expressions as possible, in this case 2 is the minimum(order doesn't matter):

```
{{c1,c2},{m1},{a1,a2}} 
{{c1},{m2},{a1}}
```

As we can see, we can easily generate original combinations from the compressed expressions.

My question is how do I generalize an algorithm to compress the combinations to fewest expressions?

I have more complex case with 4 or 5 factors.

I believe there is an existing algorithm for doing this, could you share a link to the algorithm?

Update:

A more general case with 2 factors:

Using

```
{a1,a2,a3} {c1,c2,c3}
```

we can generate

```
{a1,c1} {a1,c2} {a1,c3}, {a2,c1} {a2,c2} {a2,c3} {a3,c1} {a3,c2} {a3,c3}
```

How can I deduce

```
{{a1,a2,a3},{c1,c2,c3}}
```

from

```
{a1,c1} {a1,c2} {a1,c3}, {a2,c1} {a2,c2} {a2,c3} {a3,c1} {a3,c2} {a3,c3}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that this will be NP complete.  First generate the tree of all available ways to compactly describe several, then solve the set cover problem to find a minimal subset of those that cover all of them.

Comment: Also does multiplicity matter?  That is, is it OK if a given combination is produced twice as long as all combinations are produced?

Comment: Beat this to death with Karnaugh maps; the set coverage problem is a leaf node of that process, I think.

Comment: Are your expressions to be considered as 'sets' (unordered), or more as tuples (ordered) ? I mean, is `{a1, b1}` equivalent to `{b1, a1}` ?

Comment: @m.raynal yes, order doesn't matter.

Comment: Is it always just 3 factors?

Comment: @גלעדברקן can be 4 or 5